# Chrome extensions: get javascript to work without opening a html page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I know there is a way to make JS work in chrome extension: just include a default_popup parameter in your manifest.json to specify an HTML page, then include the JS onto the HTML using `<script>`. But is there a way to get JS to do some stuff without having to open a HTML page (e.g. change the icon of the extension without a HTML popup having to be opened)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is called [**background page**](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html). You can create it without a `.html` file, but it will dynamically create one for you, called `_generated_background_page.html`.

You can can add following to your `manifest.json` to specify a background page:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  ...
}
```

To view the background page go to `chrome://chrome/extensions` activate "Developer mode" and you can see the background page with developer tools:

[image: extensions tab]

For your example, changing the icon, you could use the [`chrome.browserAction`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html).